# How to replace bottom-right-zone click with two-finger touch/click on clickpad?

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell, wayland

At the time Ubuntu still used X11, I could do that by adding the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf`:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Default clickpad buttons"
    MatchDriver "synaptics"

    # Disable bottom right area for right click
    Option "SoftButtonAreas" "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
    Option "SecondarySoftButtonAreas" "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"

    # Enable middle click with three fingers click and tap
    Option "ClickFinger3" "2"
    Option "TapButton3" "2"
EndSection
```

How can I do that in Ubuntu 17.10?

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command as a regular user:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method 'fingers'
```