# Where does the on screen keyboard Onboard store its configuration files?

Tags: accessibility, onscreen-keyboard, onboard

Where does Onboard show its configuration files? I could not find anything in `.config`. I am running Xubuntu 22.04.

[This](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1076971) does not answer where the configuration files are located.

---

I made some changes in onboard settings, and it said that it would require GNOME accessibility. I proceeded, and now Onboard will not start (possibly because GNOME accountabilities is not installed).

My tablet does not have a physical keyboard. That's why I want to remove the configuration file to reset onboard settings, so that I can start using Onboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Theme configs** go to:

```
.local/share/onboard
```

But **app configs** are stored in binary format at:

```
${HOME}/.config/dconf/user
```

Which can be **dumped** like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1069446/19033).

Or set as **system defaults** as explained at:

```
/usr/share/onboard/onboard-defaults.conf.example
```