# cli commands to fetch and set ubuntu settings?

Tags: bash, scripts, shortcuts

Is there a pair of 2 commands that I can use to 1. store the current ubuntu settings (*the ones that you can change by going to the top right and clicking settings*) into some kind of `my_settings` file, and then 2. use the second command to set the ubuntu settings (possibly in some other installation of ubuntu) to equal to those in `my_settings`?

I want to be able to do all of this from a bash script so I can backup my settings and reset them later. **I'm primarily interested in keyboard shortcut settings, so if it only works for that, that would be good too**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save GNOME settings in a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984205/how-to-save-gnome-settings-in-a-file)

Comment: There are *tons* of different settings with different ways to access them all.  This is a very *broad* request, and therefore needs to be more narrow to properly get you an answer that'd work.

Answer (score 0):

If the only concern is keyboard shortcuts, then it's possible to use `sxhkd` (Simple X hotkey daemon).

Shortcuts are defined inside a `sxhkdrc` file, so you can backup and restore it however you like.

https://github.com/baskerville/sxhkd